# Renaming variable based on the value of the previous variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have the following data frame.

```
V1 <- c(2, 2, 2)
V2 <- c(12, 13, 24)
V3 <- c(3, 3, 3)
V4 <- c(1, 23, 33)
data <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3, V4)

data
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  2 12  3  1
2  2 13  3 23
3  2 24  3 33
```

I want to rename the V1 based on the value in `V1`. That means, I want rename the variable `V2` as `Var_2` where the number `2` comes from the `V1`.

```
  Var_2 Var_3
1    12     1
2    13    23
3    24    33
```

Any easy way to do that? I want to replicate the process for 500 variables. Is there any way avoiding loops?

Comment: Might need to add more data for a clearer picture of what you intend to do. Mix up column 1 with something not equal to 2. Otherwise why not just use `paste0` and the column index?

Comment: @NelsonGon That would always a single number. Modified the question a little bit.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest: Why "avoiding loops"?

Comment: How is the `3` from column `V3` connected to column `V4`?

Comment: The variable name starts with `Var_x`, where x is the digit from the previous variable. E.g. `V4` is to be renamed as `Var_3`, the 3 comes from `V3`. `3` is just an example, it could be other value in the previous variable that is fixed throughout the column. @markus

I am trying to get a grip on data management in R. I have got the impression from various posts here and other places that I should avoid loops as it is slow. @vaettchen

Comment: A for loop is not a 'bad' thing per se. You should avoid it when there is a vectorised  function that does the same (but more efficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` possibility:

```
data %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 arrange(rowid) %>%
 mutate(temp = ifelse(parse_number(var) %% 2 == 0, 1, NA),
        var2 = ifelse(temp == 1 & is.na(lag(temp, default = 0)), 
                      paste("Var", lag(val), sep = "_"), NA)) %>%
 na.omit() %>%
 select(-var, -temp) %>%
 spread(var2, val) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  Var_2 Var_3
1    12     1
2    13    23
3    24    33
```

First, it generates an unique row ID. Second, it transforms the data from wide to long format. Third, it checks whether the column names consist of even number. If so, it assigns 1, otherwise NA. Then, if it is an even number and the lag is NA, it combines "Var" and the value from the lagged column. Finally, it deletes the NA values and returns it back to wide format.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not getting your question, but as long as you're just needing the names from the first row of your data, something like this should work:

```
names(data) <- paste("Var",data[1,][1:ncol(data)],sep="_")

> names(data)
[1] "Var_2"  "Var_12" "Var_3"  "Var_1"
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` approach: For 500 variables you'll have to devise means of removing them not as shown here. Also it is assumed that all columns will have the same value ie 3333,2222 and so on.

```
data <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3, V4)
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data1<-data[,list(V1,V3)]
#data1[,lapply(.SD,unique)]
data[,`:=`(V1=NULL,V3=NULL)]
names(data)<-do.call("paste",list("Var_",unique(data1)))
data


    Var_ 2    Var_ 3
1:     12      1
2:     13     23
3:     24     33
```